# Invalid date/time: 7/8/2016 10:32 PM Error on Task Custom button

Tags: apex, visualforce, datetime

I have created a custom detail button on `Task`. On click of the button I am calling URL like

> /apex/TaskVF?subject={!Task.Subject}&LastModifiedDate={!Task.LastModifiedDate}.

I am getting the following error and following error displayed on the page:

> **Invalid date/time: 7/8/2016 10:32 PM**

Url:

> /apex/TaskVF?subject=Call&last=7%2F8%2F2016+10%3A32+PM

I need this `Subject` and `LastModifiedDate` in my controller to use.

Here is the code I am using to parse the `Datetime`

```
public class TaskController {
    public Datetime dt {get;set;}
    public TaskController() {
        dt =Datetime.valueof(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('last'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to pass the Id of the task you were on, then perform a query for the relevant data in the constructor of your `TaskController`? This would eliminate the date/time formatting issue you are getting.

Comment: I need to show all the tasks with same subject and same createddate/lastmodifieddate.( tasks are generated from email to salesforce). so i need these parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Datetime.parse` instead of `Datetime.valueOf`, and it can handle the format you have provided. I used it in a sample page that mimics your own. Here was my constructor:

```
public TaskController()
{
    dt = Datetime.parse(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('last'));
    system.debug(dt);
}
```

Here was the output:

> DEBUG|2016-07-09 04:32:00

Perhaps you need to do some work to get the time in the correct time zone. The following worked for me:

```
dt = Datetime.parse(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('last'));
dt = dt.newInstanceGmt(dt.date(), dt.time());
```

New output:

> DEBUG|2016-07-08 22:32:00